# Blurred image recovery?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, image-filter

I have pictures of handwritten text and some of them are blurred, because the camera was shaky. If someone could point out any techniques that I can use to bring it to readable quality would be great. It is really a closeup, and I'm pretty sure it is doable. If you can recommend a specialized software or you know some techniques in photo-shop or any other software that would help please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really an Photoshop solution but few days ago I found this application on Lifehacker.com

> Unshake, the free program which
>   analyses photos which are blurred,
>   poorly focused or shaken, and which
>   uses the results to give clearer
>   pictures.

http://www.zen147963.zen.co.uk/Unshake/Download.html

Haven't got chance to test it, but it could be good idea for you to give it a try!

good luck

Comment: The program has horrible user interface and works slow, but does the job. Results weren't perfect but were sufficient to work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a client that uses [this](http://www.focusmagic.com/) it has a free trial for 10 images, it is a very good piece of software

> Focus Magic uses advanced forensic strength deconvolution technology to literally "undo" blur and recover lost detail.  It can repair both out-of-focus blur and motion blur (camera shake) in an image.  Can you read the license plate number in the "Before" image (below) ?  Can you even vaguely make out one letter ?  Imagine how you could use this technology on your photos.